# Traceroute AWS Instance not connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, traceroute

I am new to AWS and I have created a new instance and have associated it to a domain using Route 53. However, when I visit the site on my browser I get an error:

> ### This site can’t be reached
>
> ec2-52-37-86-228.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com took too long to respond.
>
> Go to http://amazonaws.com/
>
> Search Google for ec2 228 west compute amazonaws
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I have also tried to traceroute the domain to see what was going on but it only shows this:

```
# traceroute rinosnet.com
# traceroute to rinosnet.com (52.39.244.153), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
# 1  ec2-50-112-0-96.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.112.0.96)  1.773 ms  1.811 ms ec2-50-112-0-100.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.112.0.100)  1.329 ms
# 2  * * *
# 3  * * *
# 4  * * *
# 5  * * *
# 6  * * *
# 7  * * *
# 8  * * *
# 9  * * *
# 10  * * *
# 11  * * *
# 12  * * *
# 13  * * *
# 14  * * *
# 15  * * *
# 16  * * *
# 17  * * *
# 18  * * *
# 19  * * *
# 20  * * *
# 21  * * *
# 22  * * *
# 23  * * *
# 24  * * *
# 25  * * *
# 26  * * *
# 27  * * *
# 28  * * *
# 29  * * *
# 30  * * *
```

However, when I ping the site everything works perfectly. I hope someone can help me with this or point me to right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the Security group of your Instance?

Comment: The Security group that I currently have are: HTTP - 80, SSH - 22, HTTPS - 443, All ICMP - N/A

Comment: There is some mess-up in you DNS when I ping the site I get ec2-52-39-244-153.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com but when I type the domain name www.rinosnet.com in browser it gets redirected to http://ec2-52-37-86-228.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com this are two different EC2 instances? Which instance has the actual site on it? And how is it getting redirected?

Comment: rinosnet.com is a Type A alias for www.rinosnet.com. www.rinosnet.com is where I actually have the site. www.rinosnet.com has Public DNS: ec2-52-39-244-153.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, Public IP: 52.39.244.153, Elastic IPs: 52.39.244.153*

Comment: So why is it redirecting to ec2-52-37-86-228.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com ? Is this another EC2 instance ?

Comment: I really don't know. That is one thing I have been trying to figure out. I do not have an instance with that Public DNS.

Comment: So you have to debug the application this is not issue with server it is issue with your application. What technology is the application using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu on the server for a Wordpress site. The actual Wordpress site currently does not have anything on it, and I have already tried removing the the instance and starting all over (I am currently on my third instance), and this always happens.

Comment: You installed the Wordpress site directly on the EC2 instance or you moved it from another instance to this instance?

Comment: I did a clean install. using `wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz`